# Is it possible to change a size of whole component with all of it's controllers inside (like resizing window)

Tags: css

I have a component that looks fine with 100% browser resolution...

Some users asks to display it larger and some ask for it smaller.
Of course it can be achieved by ctr + "+" / ctrl + "-" but I thought to implement a slider that the user can slide between 50% and 150% to change the size of the component as he see it suitable.

A sandbox that illustrate how the component looks like and how it's built:
https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-morning-267l5

Comment: ah, maybe you can create a setting in somewhere of the website which by activating it, you could change some styles and then  size changes

Comment: For the whole component container or for each control inside it separately?

Comment: I don't think it's possible in terms the whole component, I can control the width/height... but controls inside will stay as is! That's was the point of my question... something that can squeeze the whole div or table root control with all of it's children, like resizing window works

Comment: [Is This On Topic?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) The answer to your question is "yes". Beyond that, you are either asking for us to write code for you, opinion, or direct you to some library or other software somewhere, all of which are not allowed on SO.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get it done by sizing with a percentage

I think you can implement a slider or something which at any end of it, it activates a class in your CSS, and by the class, you can use the `width:x%` which x is the amount of you want in any of that element

Comment: you can change the width of the parent component using the slider and the by giving all of its children a width with a percentage they can change for good

Comment: font-size should be enough for the input + width for the parent

Answer (score 1):

```
var sliderthing = document.getElementById("component");
var outputthing = document.getElementById("out");

sliderthing.oninput = function() {
  outputthing.style.width = this.value;
  outputthing.style.height = this.value;
}
```

Was this what you wanted?

Or, maybe, if you want to multiply it to get a zoom effect (put this on every component of your site):

```
var sliderthing = document.getElementById("component");
var outputthing = document.getElementById("out");

sliderthing.oninput = function() {
  outputthing.style.width = outputthing.style.width * this.value;
  outputthing.style.height = outputthing.style.height * this.value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use zoom for this. Encapsule your module in a div to keep the boundaries.

> Use with care since its not working in every Browser (thx  @G-Cyr)

```js
var $range = $('#myRangeSlider');
var $module = $('#myModule');
$range.on('input', function() {
  $module.css('zoom', $(this).val() + '%');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-6">
      <input type="range" min="50" max="150" value="100" class="slider" id="myRangeSlider"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-6">
      <div id='myModule'>
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
          <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Relative Scale approach (**"Run code snippet" > "Full page" to see effect**):

```css
.module {
  font-size: 5vw;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  height: 5vw;
  width: 5vw;
}

input {
  height: 5vw;
  font-size: 5vw;
}
```

```html
<div class='module'>
  I Scale relative to the Viewport
  <br/>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" / >
    Check me
  </label><br />
  <input type="text" placeholder="bla..." />
</div>
```

Another way is to introduce css-breakpoints and set your desired font-sizes etc: https://getflywheel.com/layout/css-breakpoints-responsive-design-how-to/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom maybe transform would be a better choice ;) , even if i think it is a bad idea, it only zooms at screen , not in the document flow ;)

Comment: transform+scale was my first shot too, but it will overflow. So why may it be a better choice? Sorry i dont get your point :D
Edit: Oh compatibility, right, my bad - maybe i can improove it

Comment: i would go on width and font-size for the form elements . if it is build on grid (or similar behavior) , the column should resize without troubles. (i could not load its react link, so no idea what it is made of :( )

Comment: Yeh, but even if you know how it looks, you want the solution to work in the future aswell and we dont know how it looks in the future so we'd have to cover every possible element - but i have another idea, let me fiddle a bit :D

Comment: @zbeedatm zoom do not work with firefox  https://caniuse.com/#search=zoom . mediaquerie should do better indeed

Comment: Added a note to the post ty @G-Cyr

Comment: It's too bad that it doesn't work with Firefox, instead I tried using transform scale but it looks awful (specially for scale > 1)...  <div id="projectComponent" className="solid fixed" /*style={{zoom: this.props.zoom + "%"}}*/ style={{transform: "scale(1.5)"/*ctx.scale(this.props.zoom/100)*/}}> the zoom make it so simple cause I don't need to deal with each control in my component, but if it doesn't work with firefox I can't use it.